# Use a different JSON serializer in swagger

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger

I am using Swashbuckle for API documentation, works great but Swashbuckle seems to serialize objects in camel case, and I use NewtonSoft lib to serialize objects, which has an attribute [JsonProperty(name="")] and these are used during serialization. Is there a way I can customize Swashbuckle to use the same serializer used in the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swashbuckle 5.0 is addressing this issue(honoring JSON Attribute). More details [here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/170)